# AngularJS scenarios expect class and futures

Tags: angularjs, angular-scenario

I'm trying to write a test that checks whether or not an element has a class:

```
element('#header-menu .menu-component-item a').query(function(els, done) {
  var el = els.eq(4);

  el.click();
  sleep(.25);

  expect(browser().location().path()).toBe(el.attr('href'));
  expect(el.attr('class')).toContain('selected');
  done();
});
```

The issue is that I keep getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`. I expected `el.attr('class')` to be a future but I'm not sure why it isn't. Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `$digest()` your changes before they take effect. Try this:

```
var el = els.eq(4);

el.click();
scope.$digest();

expect(browser().location().path()).toBe(el.attr('href'));
expect(el.attr('class')).toContain('selected');
```

Although much of your code looks far to JQuery-like for an Angular app.